# How to efficiently return a 304 (Not Modified) HTTP response with Spring & MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, http

I am currently using Spring as a RESTful Web Service for a mobile application I am writing. The server-side of things is pretty well completed (in terms of functionality) but now I am trying to improve its performance.

What I want to do is find an efficient way to return 304 (Not Modified) response codes from my server to the client with an implementation that is **not shallow**. Meaning, that I want to save both bandwidth and processing cycles.

What I figured I need to do is determine the last time an object has been modified and compare it to the `if-modified-since` HTTP header. The question here is, how should I get the last updated time of an object quickly (i.e. with zero-to-minimal access to the persistence layer)? Or is there a better approach to this altogether?

Note: I have been referencing [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/etags) and [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/11/etags-for-rest-with-spring/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure mongoDB support getting the last update time. I would do it manually. Check the $currentDate operator, here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/